# How do I hide users in the same group on sharepoint from seeing eachother?

Tags: external-users

I have set up a sharepoint site and will be adding competing companies to the same site. How do I ensure the group members added will not be able to see each others detail and emails.

Comment: Do you want to limit viewing "SharePoint group" membership?

Answer (score 0):

- For hiding the existing user details with other user , create security group and add member.
- After creation of this security group add it as member in SharePoint Group.
- User will only see the group name and not the member.
- Refer this Microsoft docs for your reference

  [Create a basic group and add members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups)